# app settings dataset - color column doesn't save

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

In the settings menu in my application, one of my settings is a dataset, called "DSTimerType".
[image]

On application load, I assign that dataset to a class level variable:

```
Public Shared DSTimerType As DataSet
...
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DSTimerType = My.Settings.DSTimerType
```

And I do some checks, with DSTimerType.Tables("TableTimerSequence") assigned to local variable TableTimerSequence (datatable type).

Every time it opens, all the data in these tables is fine (integers, strings, timespans, and booleans) except for the Color columns - those always get reset to nothing.
[image]

So I reassign the colors in the code, then save the settings with:

```
My.Settings.DSTimerType = DSTimerType 'to write class variable dataset to application stored dataset
My.Settings.Save()
```

On closing, I save again for good measure. At this time, the color values are still there:
[image]

But when I reopen, everything is in the dataset except the colors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Settings are stored in a config file, which is XML.  To be saved in settings, your `DataSet` must be being written to XML and I would guess that there is an issue with XML serialisation of `Color` values. The first test I would do is call `WriteXml` and `ReadXml` with a `DataSet` and see whether the `Color` values make the round-trip. If not, that is the issue and you can at least investigate that specifically.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I may actually just break it out into R,G,B integer columns. Thanks for that.

Comment: You may prefer to have the components separate but you can use `FromArgb` and `ToArgb` to go between a `Color` and a single `Integer` and then just store that `Integer` in your settings.